# Crash in C# Class Library when i use it

Tags: c#, exception, json.net, securityexception, targetinvocationexception

Source/destination types

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    public int FirstText { get; set; }
    public int SecondText { get; set; }
}
```

Source/destination JSON

```
{FirstText:1,SecondText:2}
```

Expected behavior

When I use it in a single exe demo:
    1 - 2

Actual behavior

When I use it in a C# Class Library, it crashes:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the ta
rget of an invocation. ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOn
ly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Bo
olean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipChec
kThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean s
kipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.LateBoundReflectionDelegateFactory.<>c__DisplayC
lass9`1.<CreateDefaultConstructor>b__7()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject
(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract objectContract, JsonProperty containerMem
ber, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id, Boolean& createdFromNonDefaultCr
eator)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(Js
onReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Js
onContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object exis
tingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInte
rnal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty mem
ber, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Obje
ct existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(Jso
nReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type
 objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, Jso
nSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSeriali
zerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value)
```

Steps to reproduce

```
var test = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyStruct>("{FirstText:1,SecondText:2}");

System.Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", test.FirstText, test.SecondText);
```

When I use Json.NET in a single exe demo, it works fine.
But when I take it in a C# Class Library, it does not work.
I push a issue on github but I still ask there because I am too nervous to wait...

Comment: The function & struct & class are all Public.

Comment: The function which call Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject is set [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Assert, Unrestricted = true)].

Comment: Maybe you need to add more information. I just built a minimum example of what I understood you are trying and it worked just fine. Can you post the structure of your solution?

Comment: First I use C++ ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain to execute Sandbox.Bootstrap (a C# class library) and then I call AppDomain.Load to load a assembly and call MethodBase.Invoke to trigger the new lib's function.Final I use Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject and get exception...

Comment: This seems to be very relevant information since you're dealing with a `SecurityException`. Unfortunately, I have zero expertise in this and therefore can't help from here on.

Comment: This question needs more context. Please provide a better description on what you're try to achieve and what you have tried.

Comment: See the answer below. I change a way to code them but still get exception.

Comment: What I have tried is just use JSON.NET to resolve a struct like MyStruct in C# class library but failed.

Comment: AppDomain.Load and Invoke the specific assembly's function. The function is supposed to resolve a json file.

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that the JSON you are providing is not valid.
Keys must be wrapped in quotes. Try this:
`{ "FirstText": 1, "SecondText": 2 }`

Edit: If you're planning on hardcoding the JSON inside the source then, make sure to escape it so it can be interpreted correctly.

Comment: I write a JSON file:
{
  "123": {
    "FirstText": 1,
    "SecondText": 2
  }
}

Comment: My new code is:
                JToken value;
                if (JObject.Parse(Encoding.Default.GetString(Properties.Resources.MyTest)).TryGetValue("123", out value))
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine(value.ToString());
                    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyStruct>(value.ToString());
                    System.Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", obj.FirstText, obj.SecondText);
                }

Comment: Output is:
{
  "FirstText": 1,
  "SecondText": 2
}
System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOn
ly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Bo
olean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipChec
kThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean s
kipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)

Comment: at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.LateBoundReflectionDelegateFactory.<>c__DisplayC
lass9`1.<CreateDefaultConstructor>b__7()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject
(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract objectContract, JsonProperty containerMem
ber, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id, Boolean& createdFromNonDefaultCr
eator)

Comment: at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(Js
onReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Js
onContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object exis
tingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInte
rnal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty mem
ber, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Obje
ct existingValue)

Comment: at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(Jso
nReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type
 objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, Jso
nSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSeriali
zerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value)

Answer (score 0):

Sandboxed AppDomain required full trust with references and it can be given by two way:
 1. Registed assembly in GAC.
 2. Set assembly is fullTrustAssemblies with StrongName when use AppDomain.CreateDomain.